# Hosting Angular 11 with SSR in IIS and error Error: Cannot find module

Tags: angular

I have deployed simple SSR angular app on IIS and it work properly
then I try to deploy test application(more complex one) and I found this error

> Blockquote

```
(node:47384) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './vendors~components-pages-about-about-module-ngfactory~components-pages-contact-contact-module-ngfact~7b482290.js'
Require stack:
- D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js
- C:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js**
Error: Cannot find module './vendors~components-pages-about-about-module-ngfactory~components-pages-contact-contact-module-ngfact~7b482290.js'
Require stack:
- D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js
- C:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Function.requireEnsure [as e] (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:512)
    at app_routing_module_0 (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:3818643)
    at router_RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:2413504)
   
ERROR NetworkError
    at XMLHttpRequest.send (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:1845847)
    at Observable_Observable._subscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:1527358)
    at Observable_Observable._trySubscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:1488377)
    at Observable_Observable.subscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:1488159)
    at D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:3660982
    at Observable_Observable._subscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:3661327)
    at Observable_Observable._trySubscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:1488377)
    at Observable_Observable.subscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:1488159)
    at innerSubscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:4163009)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:195484)
ERROR NetworkError
    at XMLHttpRequest.send (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:1845847)
    at Observable_Observable._subscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:1527358)
    at Observable_Observable._trySubscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:1488377)
    at Observable_Observable.subscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:1488159)
    at D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:3660982
    at Observable_Observable._subscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:3661327)
    at Observable_Observable._trySubscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:1488377)
    at Observable_Observable.subscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:1488159)
    at innerSubscribe (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:4163009)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (D:\Deploy\Web\TestSSR\angular-universal\main.js:1:195484)
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './vendors~components-pages-about-about-module-ngfactory~components-pages-contact-contact-module-ngfact~7b482290.js'
```

> Blockquote

And here is web.config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAVsv.png)

How can I fix this error. please.